# How can I convert an 8bit unsigned wave file, to an 8bit signed wave file?

Tags: c#, audio, naudio, wave, type-conversion

I'm using NAudio with C# to convert wave files to 48,000, 8bit, Mono. I'm storing the converted data in a byte array. My code is below. It works fine, but the new wave file data is unsigned, and I need it to be signed.

```
WaveFormat target = new WaveFormat(48000, 8, 1);
WaveStream stream = new WaveFileReader(this.FilePath);
WaveFormatConversionStream conv = new WaveFormatConversionStream(target, stream);
this.ConvertedData = new byte[conv.Length];
conv.Position = 0;
conv.Read(this.ConvertedData, 0, Convert.ToInt32(conv.Length));
stream.Dispose();
conv.Dispose();
```

I've tried looping through the byte array after the data is converted, and subtracting 128 from each byte, which is a solution that I found on this site.

```
for (int i = 0; i < end; i++)
{
    signed = (int)this.ConvertedData[i] - 128;
    this.Data[i] = (byte)signed;
}
```

This kind of works, but is not fool proof, and I'm sure there has to be a better way. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: according to this description of wav file format, when you use 8-bit the values can only be unsigned. http://www.sonicspot.com/guide/wavefiles.html "when samples are represented with 8-bits, they are specified as unsigned values"

Comment: not sure if this site will help but it may provide a better explanation about what you can and can't do 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11711689/remove-the-headers-from-several-wav-files-and-then-concatenate-the-remaining-da

Answer (score 0):

```
WaveFormat target = new WaveFormat(48000, 8, 1);
WaveStream stream =new WaveFileReader(this.FilePath);
WaveFormatConversionStream str = new WaveFormatConversionStream(target, stream);
WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile("c:\\converted.wav", str); //or the path of .wav file
```

try using the WaveFileWriter.CreateFile method instead..

Checkout [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/)
This link you can checkout too they have a C# audio library
[Alvis.Audio](http://alvas.net/alvas.audio.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment, so I have to "misuse" the answer function:

try:

```
Convert.toSByte
```

It is String based but should work...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0hdkwd9.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking a better way to convert from unsigned byte array to signed byte array, you can use Buffer.BlockCopy method, or try with sbyte[] signed = (sbyte[])(Array)unsigned . Hope it helps.